# use .Net 2.0 dll in .net 4.0 wpf application

Tags: c#, .net-4.0, clr

I am trying to add a reference to a .Net 2.0 DLL in a WPF application that is targeted to the .Net 4 Framework.

I added `<startup useLegacyV2RuntimeActivationPolicy="true">` to the app.config file. The WPF app builds fine, but gets a BadImageFormatException at Runtime when trying to access the .Net 2.0 DLL.

"An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format"

This works with a new test WPF project, but does not work on my app. My app uses Entity Framework and MEF. Could these technologies be causing the issue?

Any ideas?

**Edit: Resolved**

According to the comment by Alois below, I had my main app targeted to 'Any CPU' and the DLL was targeted to 32-bit.

`<startup useLegacyV2RuntimeActivationPolicy="true">` was not required

Comment: Could it be that the assembly is compiled for 32 bit and you are loading it into a 64 bit process or vice versa? Use corflags from the .NET Framework SDK to check.

Comment: @Alois: Thanks. I hadn't thought of that. My app was targeted to 'Any CPU'. Changing it to x86 lets it load correctly.

Answer (score 2):

When you have to use the useLegacyV2RuntimeActivationPolicy attribute then you are working with a mixed-mode assembly that was written in C++/CLI and targeting version 2.0.50727 of the CLR.  Such an assembly contains both managed code and native machine code.  That machine code is 32-bit in your case, you can't run it in a 64-bit process.  Which is what the exception means.  Setting the Platform target to x86 in your EXE project is required.

Comment: Yes. See the above comments in the question. It was already figured out that I was loading 32-bit code in a 64-bit process. Also, the useLegacyV2RuntimeActivationPolicy was not required. It was only the 32-bit problem. I was able to remove useLegacyV2RuntimeActivationPolicy="true"